# Retrieve config value from sales channel in plugin settings

Tags: vue.js, shopware, shopware6

How can I retrieve values from the plugin config for a specific sales channel? I need to validate an API-Token, but can only retrieve the value stored for all sales channels and don't know how my custom admin component could even know about its current sales channel.

Currently, I am retrieving values via the following code, which follows the [example plugin from Shopware](https://github.com/shyim/ShyimApiTest), but they too only retrieve the global value.

```
Component.register('my-component', {
    computed: {
        getMyKey() {
            return this.pluginConfig['MyPlugin.config.myKey'];
        },
        pluginConfig() {
            let $parent = this.$parent;
            while ($parent.actualConfigData === undefined) {
                $parent = $parent.$parent;
            }
            return $parent.actualConfigData.null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to inject `systemConfigApiService` and use it to retrieve the config values. `getValues` takes a second argument for the sales channel id.

```js
Component.register('my-component', {
    inject: ['systemConfigApiService'],
    methods: {
        getConfig(salesChannelId) {
            const values =  this.systemConfigApiService
                .getValues('MyPlugin.config', salesChannelId);

            return values.myKey;
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: That looks very helpful. How could I retrieve the current sales channel from the admin UI? Is there a method like `this.systemConfigApiService.getCurrentSalesChannelId()`?

Comment: There is no sales channel id in the administration. It depends on the domain used to request the storefront. You could have an entity select dropdown where the user has to actively select a sales channel and then pass the selected entities id to fetch the config for that specific sales channel.

Comment: Oh, maybe I was a bit unclear as to where I would like to use that component. In the plugin settings generated by the `config.xml` there is already such a dropdown. I assumed that it should be possible to retrieve the currently selected channel via some service.